# Sorting data.frame but leave NA linked to original value

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, na

```
data <- data.frame(value = c(1,NA,2,NA,3,NA), col1 = c("A1","B1","A2","B2","A3","B3"), col2 = c("X","Y","Z","Q","R","S"))
```

tried

```
> data <- data.frame(value = c(1,NA,2,NA,3,NA), col1 = c("A1","B1","A2","B2","A3","B3"), col2 = c("X","Y","Z","Q","R","S"))
> sorted_indices <- order(data$value)
> data <- data[sorted_indices,]
> data
```

```
 data <- data[order(data$value, data$col1),]
```

and

dplyr

```
data %>% 
+     arrange(value, order_by(col1)
```

with result like

```
  value col1 col2
1     1    A1    X
3     2    B2    Z
5     3    C4    R
2    NA    A1    Y
4    NA    B2    Q
6    NA    C3    S
```

I need:
2,NA,1,NA,3,NA order of data$value
and
A2,B2,A1,B1,A3,B3 order of data$col1
as final result.

Comment: You want to sort, but with 1 after 2 but before 3?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I need 2 on top and no change in other order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need an `ordered` factor since you want manual order. You can use `zoo::na.locf` to keep NAs with the original value:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(value2 = ordered(zoo::na.locf(value), c(2, 1, 3))) %>% 
  arrange(value2) %>% 
  select(-value2)

  value col1 col2
1     2   A2    Z
2    NA   B2    Q
3     1   A1    X
4    NA   B1    Y
5     3   A3    R
6    NA   B3    S
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i need NAs in value to show this dataset in shiny dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution without dplyr but with maditr

```
#init
data$value2 = data$value
i <- 2

#fill NAs with original value
while (i <= length(data$value2)) {
    if (is.na(data$value2[i])) {
        data$value2[i] <- data$value2[i - 1]
    }
    i <- i + 1
}

# make custom order factor
custom_rows_sort_order <- c(2,1,3) #get this value from input$selector selected order reactively
data$value2 <- ordered(data$value2,custom_rows_sort_order)

#sort
res_table <- data[order(data$value2),] %>% 
    cols(-value2)
```